# How many graphs can be formed from $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many graphs can be formed from $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ vertices? The vertices are labelled and hence distinguishable.

The answer is given to be $2^{n\choose{2}}$.

Someone, please explain this to me.

Comment: It should be emphasized that in this problem, the vertices are understood to be *labeled vertices*.  The counting problem for the number of graphs on $n$ *unlabeled vertices* is considerably harder.  See https://oeis.org/A000088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $n$ vertices, then there are ${n \choose 2}$ possible pairs of vertices. For each pair of vertices, there are two options: there could be an edge, or not an edge. So $2^{n \choose 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the set of vertices fixed, all you need to form a graph is to determine the set of edges.

The set $S$ of unordered pairs (of distinct elements) of $\{1, ..., n\}$ has $\dbinom{n}{2}$ elements.

Each subsets of $S$ corresponds to a unique graph in a bijective manner. There are precisely $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ such subsets.